# Filter a document library from a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, filter, modern-experience, json-formatting

I have a list and a document library that I'd like to link.

I would love to be able to have a link in the list that would search the document library based on a specific field.

Example:

The list contains claim data, including a claims number. I would like a link or button as a column where a user can click it and it would search the document library for that claims number and present the documents for that claims number.

I have tried using built in filters on the list and library but can't get anything to work.

I am using SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharePoint JSON [Column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) to create a link in list view.

I am using below JSON code to create a link in list view. On click of link, it will open a new tab with filtered document library:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "= 'Search Library for' + [$Title]",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "= @currentWeb + '/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?view=7&q=' + [$Title]",
    "target": "_blank"
  }
}
```

Here I am using "Title" column. You can use any column as per your requirements, just make sure you are using correct **internal name** of column. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

**List view**:

[image]

**Library with search results**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much, this has worked perfectly!