# Link from SharePoint Library to list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, folder

We create a SharePoint list record and a flow that populates the list and also creates a folder in a SharePoint library, this folder has subfolders.

The list has a title called (enq_no), this title is used in the creation of the folder and I have been able to pull the enq_no in to a column on the subfolders.

What the business would like to do is have a link in these subfolders that opens the list item.

How do I create a link in the subfolder to open the list item?

I am a novice at all of this.

Comment: You will need SharePoint list item "ID" in one of the columns in document library to generate link to specific list item.

Comment: Did you try solution given below?

Answer (score 0):

Try below suggestions:

1. Create one more column in document library and pull the item **ID** from list into this column against the subfolders.
2. Use SharePoint JSON [Column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) on above column to create a link to specific list item in library view.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "Link to item",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "=@currentWeb + '/lists/listName/dispform.aspx?ID=' + @currentField",
    "target": "_blank"
  }
}
```

Replace `listName` with URL name of your SharePoint list.

**Similar thread**: [Filter a document library from a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290946/filter-a-document-library-from-a-list/290947#290947)

Comment: If you cannot pull item ID in library column, you can generate link to filtered list view based on `enq_no` column. But bringing item ID and using JSON formatting as explained in above answer will be best possible solution.